# How can I capture new relic logs from a background python process I launch in an ECS container

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, newrelic

Here is the startup shell script for the container:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set environment variables for newrelic

if [ -z "${ENVIRONMENT}" ]; then
    export NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="tf-ai-service-update-LOCAL"
else
    export NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="tf-${APP_NAME}-${ENVIRONMENT}"
fi

# Start one rq worker in the background 
pipenv run newrelic-admin run-program rq worker --config rq_config --with-scheduler ai-service-update & 

# Start the Flask app using newrelic-admin
pipenv run newrelic-admin run-program flask --app app run --host=0.0.0.0
```

The scripts starts two processes the worker and flask.  We only get new relic logs for the flask app.  We want to capture stdout and stderr for the worker process.

We tried adding the `newrelic-admin run-program` command in front of the command that launches the worker.  This is how we capture logs into new relic for the flask app.  There are no logs from the worker being sent to new relic.